# In what units pymongo geo2d aggregate result is returned

Tags: python, pymongo, geospatial

I am having records as below in my mongodb collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ecf141624bc0798ee5882d"),
    "username" : "user.sthlm",
    "location" : [ 
        18.0686, 
        59.3293
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ecf141624bc0798ee5882e"),
    "username" : "user.malmo",
    "location" : [ 
        13.0038, 
        55.605
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ecf141624bc0798ee5882f"),
    "username" : "user.la",
    "location" : [ 
        -118.2437, 
        34.0522
    ]
}
```

"location" is a "2dsphere" type and it is in order [longitude, latitude]

Now I am using a pymongo query as below to retrieve distance between a given point

(Stockholm Coordinates)
longitude = 18.0686
latitude = 59.3293

```
for doc in self.users.aggregate([{"$geoNear": {"near": [longitude, latitude],
                                                           "distanceField":"distance",
                                                           "distanceMultiplier": 1.0,
                                                           "num": int(count),
                                                           "spherical": True}}]):
```

The result is as follows

```
  {
      "distance": 0,
      "username": "user.sthlm"
    },
    {
      "distance": 0.08048218816530191,
      "username": "user.malmo"
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.393869662777678,
      "username": "user.la"
    }
```

In the query response the distance between Stockholm and LA is retuned as 1.393869662777678. I am not quite sure in which unit it is in.

From google maps, distance between the coordinates is 8,875 kms or 5,515 miles and 1.3938 doesn't fit either bill. From mongoDB documentation, i refer the result is NOT returned in radians. So I am wondering what to refer from my query response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance *is* returned in radians. Convert (very approximately) radians to km by multiplying by 6371.

6371 * 1.393 = 8874 km, as expected.